# Scheduled Job In Parse.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, job-scheduling, parse-cloud-code

I want to run Cloud Code with scheduled Job in Parse.(sashido.io)

**randomMentor** function picks the some object in my `Class` with random number and saving it `Today` Class. When I call this method from Swift via `PF.Cloud.callFunctionInBackground` it **works** pretty well.

But I couldn't work from the **Parse Dashboard**. I created a scheduled job in my Dashboard with `pickTodaysMentor` name and it tries to run with `Parse.cloud.run` closure. **But it always return with:** `error loading cloud code Parse.Cloud.define is not a function`

There is my functions.js;

```
Parse.Cloud.define('randomMentor', async function (request, response) {
    var Mentor = Parse.Object.extend('Mentor');
    var countQuery = new Parse.Query(Mentor);
    const count = await countQuery.count();
    const query = new Parse.Query('Mentor');
    const randomInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
    query.equalTo('position', randomInt);
    query.limit(1); // limit to at most 10 results
    const results = await query.find();

    const Today = Parse.Object.extend('Today');
    const today = new Today();
    today.set('mentor', results[0]);
    today.save()
        .then((today) => {
            response.success("Today Mentor Created.");
        }, (error) => {
            response.error(error);
        });
    response.success("Today Mentor Created.");
});

Parse.Cloud.job('pickTodaysMentor', (request) => {
    const { params, headers, log, message } = request;
    message("I just started");
    Parse.Cloud.run('randomMentor', {}, {
        success: function (result) {
        },
        error: function (error) {
        }
    });
});
```

I am not a JS Developer so couldn't find any solution. I digged tutorials, guides and a search engine but no luck. I think error is too generic for finding the issue.

What do you think?

Comment: parse-server version ?

Comment: Parse Server v3.1.3

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Your answer is not contain my question. It's only example. By the way, my problem is solved. It was a server issue. Code works well. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: Problem solved. It was a server issue. Codes are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving means that your Cloud Code function is invalid.

It should look something like this in versions of Parse Server 3.0.0 and above:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("function", async (request) => {
  return "Hello World";
});
```